Go jwt.ParseWithClaims issue
func ValidateJWT(tokenString, tokenSecret string) (uuid.UUID, error) {
    token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(tokenString, &jwt.RegisteredClaims{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
       
        if _, ok := token.Method.(*jwt.SigningMethodHMAC); !ok {
            log.Printf("unexpected signing method: %v", token.Header["alg"])
            return nil, errors.New("unexpected signing method")
        }
        return []byte(tokenSecret), nil
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error parsing token: %v", err)
        return uuid.Nil, err 
    }

    if claims, ok := token.Claims.(*jwt.RegisteredClaims); ok && token.Valid {
        userID, err := uuid.Parse(claims.Subject)
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("Error parsing user ID from claims: %v", err)
            return uuid.Nil, err
        }
        return userID, nil
    }

    log.Println("could not extract claims from token")
    return uuid.Nil, errors.New("could not extract claims")
}


I have been trying to validate a token right after generating it, but the ParseWithClaims part keeps returning the error:
token is malformed: could not base64 decode header: illegal base64 data at input byte 0

Example token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJjaGlycHkiLCJzdWIiOiJhMTIzZmRlZC00MDlhLTQ2YjAtYTI4Mi0wYzlhNDdhYjNmZWIiLCJleHAiOjE3Mjc4NjMwMTYsImlhdCI6MTcyNzg1OTQxNn0.ir-ZGH_LluAHDLWEJog4aJ681ByidoYyyeC5_Gb1HbI
TokenSecret: gm0Bx90rG/8Rup6peskqYWABEqjZyV6WrFKXraMG10y8X3mLgghbORBz4ZYQQhN4lXTP3ByOHAPmn7nW4Teeag
these are the handlers and support methods:
func (cfg *apiConfig) SaveHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    type BodyPayload struct {
        Body string    `json:"body"`
        Id uuid.UUID    `json:"id"`
        
    }

    req := BodyPayload{}
    err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&req)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"error": "something went wrong"})
        return
    }

    
    Jwt, err := auth.GetBearerToken(r.Header)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Could not get bearer token", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Validate the JWT
    JWTid, err := auth.ValidateJWT(Jwt, cfg.Secret)
    if err != nil {
        
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)  //error accirs here
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"error": "error parsing token"})
        return
    }

    if JWTid != req.Id{
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"error": "invalid or expired token"})
        return
    }
    
    if len(req.Body) > 140 {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"error": "chirp too long"})
        return
    }

    wordsToCensor := []string{"kerfuffle", "sharbert", "fornax"}
    censored := censorText(req.Body, wordsToCensor)

    type ResponseBody struct {
        Id        uuid.UUID    `json:"id"`
        CreatedAt time.Time     `json:"created_at"`
        UpdatedAt time.Time     `json:"updated_at"`
        Body      string       `json:"body"`
        UserID    uuid.UUID    `json:"user_id"`
    }

    // Here, you can use the validated JWTid to associate the chirp with the user
    user, err := cfg.dbQueries.SaveUser(r.Context(), database.SaveUserParams{
        Body:   censored,
        UserID: req.Id, 
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error creating user: %v", err)
        http.Error(w, "Could not create user", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    resp := ResponseBody{
        Id:        user.ID,
        CreatedAt: user.CreatedAt,
        UpdatedAt: user.UpdatedAt,
        Body:      censored,
        UserID:    user.UserID,
    }

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(resp); err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Failed to encode response", http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}

func GetBearerToken(headers http.Header) (string, error) {
    // Get the Authorization header
    tokenString := headers.Get("Authorization")

    // Check if the Authorization header is present
    if tokenString == "" {
        return "", errors.New("authorization header missing")
    }

    // Check if it starts with "Bearer "
    if !strings.HasPrefix(tokenString, "Bearer ") {
        return "", errors.New("invalid authorization header format")
    }

    // Remove the "Bearer " prefix and trim any extra whitespace
    token := strings.TrimSpace(strings.TrimPrefix(tokenString, "Bearer "))

    // Return the token and no error
    return token, nil
}

any suggestion is welcome, thank you
I have logged the token when it was passed into the ValidateJWT function and it seems fine
Edit:

can you log the token after you remove the Bearer? There is possiblity of the token is empty

Log or print the token to ensure it's correctly formatted but make sure this happens only in the development phase !
Also confirm that the token is passed correctly and hasn't been altered.
"Illegal Base64 Data" typically occurs when the data under the data field is not correctly encoded in base64
